# How to give write permissions only to UI app to write data to a Spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet, google-sheets-api

I have developed a web application using Google scripts UIApp class which will collect the data of work done by each associate and writes data to my spreadsheet.
Problem I'm facing is I have to share my spreadsheet to all the associates with write permission where it enables them to see others data. I want to hide this sheet from all but they should also be able write data using the web application I shared.

Please let me know for more details or any code snippets

Note: I have Not used Google Form because I need change the list values dynamically based on the selection and the type of user.

Comment: If you Script create a Google Spreadsheet , your folder in your drive has a specific access.  so if your folder has a public access , anybody can write in your spreadsheet in your script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can deploy the app you have built with UiApp to be executed as "you" and allow access to anyone.  The spreadsheet won't need to be shared anymore but as it is anyone (even anonymous if you are not in a domain) will be able to use it...

You'll have to implement an access control yourself, again this will be different in a domain or in a "normal" gmail account (in a domain you can get the user email, in a gmail account you can't)

Answer (score 0):

(since apparently I can't comment.. but to follow up on this question.)

Is there a best practice for running as something other than really-yourself?

Say a team is managing it, or your a contractor who won't stay with the company, and so you're account and access is likely to go away.

I assume it results in creating a shared account, or perhaps a groups or something?  You start getting into all sorts of ACL issues.  And a simple ``run as yourself'' doesn't seem like a good long term solution.